# Cannot use audio file error in Phonegap / iOS7 project

Tags: javascript, cordova, mp3

I am getting an error: `Cannot use audio file from resource 'audio/sound1.mp3` when trying to play a sound file in my Phonegap app on iOS7.

There are other sound files in the audio folder, I have no problem playing them when running the phonega['s `play()` function, just this file, The MP3 file plays normal on my computer though, so I assume that's not a problem with the sound file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to build the project so the file can be read and played.